# Can I use cassandra with heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, cassandra

Is it possible to use cassandra with heroku?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No and yes.

It depends on whether you mean use a Heroku-hosted Cassandra instance or not. If that's what you mean then the answer is **no** (for now at least). They support PostrgeSQL within their stack and MySQL through Amazon RDS. MongoDB support is in beta (partnering with MongoHQ) and CouchDB is roadmapped for later this year (in conjunction with Cloudant).

But of course there's no technical reason to stop you from deploying Cassandra elsewhere (say on EC2) to work with your Heroku app. So in this context the answer is **yes**.

UPDATE (2012/09):

Heroku has launched a new add-on for Cassandra hosted by Cassandra.io. Details available [here](https://addons.heroku.com/cassandraio).

UPDATE (2014/11):

The Heroku Cassandra beta addon is no longer available nor does [cassandra.io](http://cassandra.io) seem to exist anymore. ATM no Cassandra addon is available so only rolling your own as detailed above is possible.

Comment: Now there's an instaclustr plugin for Cassandra on Heroku https://elements.heroku.com/addons/instaclustr

Answer (score 6):

Yes take a look at http://cassandra.io for a hosted Cassandra solution and heroku addon.

We are in private beta as you can see here: https://addons.heroku.com/cassandraio

You can provision the addon using the following command:

heroku addons:add cassandraio

Comment: Uhh, I don't see the add-on at Heroku nor can I add it using the heroku client.

Comment: You may get into the private beta with us.

Comment: I signed up and got an email but was super confused by the whole process. Perhaps we can talk further via email. I'm [mywholename]   at gmail.

Answer (score 1):

There is a Cassandra [heroku add-on](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/instaclustr) available for [Instaclustr](https://www.instaclustr.com/).

Answer (score -1):

This is no longer the case. There is a company with a solution currently seeking testers:
http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.db.hector.user/4928